# Use other database connection and execute query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, thread-safety, database-connection

In our app, we need to switch to read replica database and read from it for some read-only APIs.

We decided to use the around_action filter for that:

1. Switch DB to read_replica before the action
2. Yield
3. Switching back to master.

We decided to use establish_connection for switching, which did the job but later we noticed that it's not thread-safe i.e it causes our other threads to face `"#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with 'primary' found.>"`  issue. So this solution would have worked in the case of single-threaded servers.

Later we tried to create a new connection pool, as below which is thread-safe:

```
  databases = Rails.configuration.database_configuration
  resolver = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification::Resolver.new(databases)
  spec = resolver.spec(:read_replica)
  pool = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.new(spec)
  pool.with_connection { |conn|
    execute SQL query here.
  }
```

The only problem with the above approach is, we can only execute queries using execute method like `conn.execute(sql_query)` any AR ORM query we execute inside this with_connection block run on the original DB and not read_replica.

Seems like ActiveRecord do have its default connection and it's using it when we run AR ORM queries.

Not sure how can we execute the AR ORM query inside the with_connection block as `User.where(id: 1..10)`.

Please note:

1. I am aware that we can do this natively in rails 6, need to skip that for now.
2. I am also aware of the Octopus gem, again need to skip on that.

Appreciate any help, Thanks.

Comment: What are you querying from the replica? Are you saying sometimes you need a model to read from one db and sometimes from another? This is going to be nearly impossible from my experience. What I have done in the past (prior to rails 6) was create a separate connection class that inherits from AR::Base and then inherited from that for some models and inherited from AR::Base for others to create a multi database platform but you appear to be asking to use the full power of the ORM while also context switching databases adhoc and this I am not sure is possible (even in rails 6).

Comment: Yes @engineersmnk, I need the same model and 2 DB(one original and one replica). Also, I have checked the method you explained above, is this correct above that: `class ReadReplica < AR::Base` establish_connection to read_replica for this. Then for any model I need, I can inherit the above class for reading from the replica. Right?

The only problem I see above for us is, We will need to change most of the code for this(say changing the model classes to those read replica model classes). Correct me if  I am wrong.

Comment: `how can we execute the AR ORM query` --> try this `def connect_db(db) ..your above code... pool.with_connection { |conn| query = yield; conn.execute(query.to_sql) }`

Comment: @LamPhan, We are able to execute that. We will need to make changes throughout to make it work thought, which is not feasible and maintainable as well. So we need `User.first` to be executed and not `conn.execute(query.to_sql)`. The AR ORM query run but on default connection i.e original DB.

Comment: We implemented something similar with Rails 4.  We have each model "connected" to 50 databases for multi tenant support. Each tenant's model operations are run in a separate thread and, corresponding connections are fetched based on the thread local variable.   Said that, the whole thing is pretty brittle, and there is some nasty connection methods overridding that needs to happen.  Even though it works, every now and then we find issues with this approach (like caching etc).  I wouldn't recommend going this route, at least in Rails 4.